# Global Namespace in JavaScript vs Java

Tags: javascript, java, namespaces

I came across this line 'In JavaScript, all the code shares a single global namespace'. I want to confirm if my understanding is correct.

My understanding:

In ***JAVA***:

Application 1 -> (has a variable called) outputText = "Morning"

Application 2 -> (has a variable called) outputText = "Evening"

Since the two projects have different memory allocations, they have different namespace containers, and there is no danger of the variables getting mixed up. So printing Application1.outputText gives "Morning", and Application2.outputText gives "Evening".

In ***JAVASCRIPT***:

Application 1 -> (has a variable called) outputText = "Morning"

Application 2 -> (has a variable called) outputText = "Evening"

Since they share the same namespace containers, Application1.outputText may give "Evening".

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's correct. AFAIK if you define a class/object `A` in JavaScript and do that in two places you'll either get an error or the second definition overrides the first definition. You'd get the same if you'd put two Java classes into the same package but if you put them into different packages the packages act as namespaces for those classes. JavaScript doesn't know packages so you can't do that there.

Comment: If they are different application they don't share global scope, they would need to be running in the same page to share global scope.

Comment: It really depends on where the variable is and what you consider an application. Browser scripts share the highest scope but NodeJS/ES6 modules do not. Also, not all the code is being shared on the global scope. You do have function scope and block scope in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "application", but the short answer is yes, that is correct.

The longer answer is that normal javascript "best practice" is to carefully scope your variables.  So the global namespacing only applies to variables/functions that aren't declared within a function (or self evoking function) or as an object property.

So something like this:

```
var outPutText = "morning";
```

Then in another file somewhere...possibly in a poorly written API:

```
var outPutText = "evening";
```

Will contain the value of whichever of those is encountered last when executing.

What we do in Javascript are things like:

```
var application1;
application1.outPutText = "morning";
```

And somewhere else:

```
var application2;
application2.outPutText = "evening";
```

Or, similarly, since everything in Javascript is an object, including functions:

```
function application1(){
    var outPutText = "morning";
}
function application2(){
    var outPutText = "evening";
}
```

With the latter two, you will have separated variables and different results.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there is no such global scope to declare your variables at. Everything should be declared inside classes. However in JavaScript situations differ. In JavaScript we have one shared global scope.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    // here is global scope
    var a = 1;
</script>
<script>
    console.log(a); // prints '1'
</script>
```

Java:

```
public class App1{
    public static int a = 1;
}

public class App2{
    public static int a = 2;
}
...
// somewhere inside a method
App1.a // '1'
App2.a // '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you do not have classes, just functions (same as methods if you are coming from Java).  You essentially have a long page of similar functions that correspond to a specific set of tasks.  The idea of the global name space is that area that outside of these functions.  So it is considered good practice to declare all of your variables locally within your functions.  This prevents "polluting" the global name space, which is the idea of when multiple people working on a project are all contributing code, there is a chance that the same variables names could be used.  If multiple variables of the same name are declared globally, it could cause problems with the code.

In Java you declare all of your variables in classes and never outside of them so there isn't a global space that can be declared to.